# There is no service in angular material 2! what is the equivalent for $mdMedia

Tags: angular-material2

I am going to use angular 2-material. I explored its website **material.angular.io**  but I did not find any service defined there. I could not find anything to be equivalent to $mdMedia in angular Js material. What do I do if I want to hide an element when we are in a small device?

Comment: Regardless of which frontend JS framework you use, you can still use [CSS media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/#css-media-queries) (with visibility:hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout has been decoupled from Angular Material. For easy-to-use Angular-friendly media and layout tools, check out https://github.com/angular/flex-layout